# Objective-C: Inject code into delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c

#### What I want

I want to add some logging code into my app without having to update all of my view controllers.

#### What I've tried

I attempted to add a category to `UIViewController` and override one of the delegate methods. However, this produced several warnings/errors.

Is there a way for me to inject code into all of my app's ViewControllers?

Comment: Jason, have you found a solution that answers your needs?

Comment: While I don't advocate it, method swizzling answers what I wanted. However, I took the time to properly subclass/protocol the login methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [method swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling). It is a powerful tool and can save you a lot of time. Swizzle one of the methods you wish to have logs in, and then call the original method to have it do what it is originally supposed to.

Comment: I personally would avoid this.  Seems like trouble down the road if Apple decides to change implementation of superclasses that you are swizzling against.

Comment: @ElJay You don't think he would add logging in this way to his production code?

Comment: @android - not sure I understand your question.  I think the concept is interesting, but hackish enough that I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @android Why not? We have it in our production software.

Comment: @android It certainly can't hurt to emphasize that he shouldn't :)

Comment: @ElJay If done correctly, there is nothing hackish about it. This is why we have Objective C.

Comment: What you choose to have in your production code is entirely your decision.  I am just saying I would rather go the conventional route of subclassing and using that super class for this kind of thing.

Comment: And what is a "conventional way"? Why limit yourself to other programming languages' conventions, when you are using Objective C? The Objective C runtime is very much a convention of Objective C. Also, it solves his problem with 5 lines of code.

Comment: @ElJay, in a perfect world, I agree. However, this solution may be an answer to the question at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass UIViewController and then add the logging methods in your super class.  You would still need to touch all of your VC's though and change the class to your super class though.

Comment: And what if he wants to have logging in a view controller that is closed source?

Comment: @LeoNatan: we subclass closed source view controller every day.

Comment: Well, you probably couldn't do this except with controllers that you have created and have source for.  Not saying it is the only or best way, but is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't possibly have so many view controller classes in an iOS app that touching each one will be a huge problem. So create your own UIViewController subclass, maybe `OurSuperViewController` that'll act as a superclass for your view controllers, and add the logging there. Then modify each of your view controller classes so that they inherit from `OurSuperViewController`, and make sure that each one calls `super` in the relevant view controller methods.

Once you've done that, you can turn logging on or off at will by modifying just `OurSuperViewController`.

Comment: Gee that sounds like what I was thinking :)

Comment: I agree with you. However, this became a challenge, and at this point, I wanted to know if it *could* be done. Depending on the answers, I may indeed touch every controller.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary There are all kinds of tricks you can play (like method swizzling) with the runtime, but if it's all your code it rarely makes sense to do so because it adds complexity that'll bite you later.

Comment: @Caleb I disagree that using the runtime creates complexity. I think it actually brings a very elegant simplicity. Once you understand what is going on, you are in for a great ride.

Comment: @LeoNatan Schemes like method swizzling have their place, certainly, but it's hard to argue that they don't add complexity. In the case of swizzling, you go from: *`[b foo]` causes `B`'s `-foo` method to be called* to the more complex: *`[b foo]` causes `B`'s `-bar` method to be called because in this particular case we used the runtime to switch the methods around*. Now, it may be particularly handy that you can do that sometimes, and it may be better/more elegant than available alternatives, but it's a) not obvious and b) unexpected. So put a big fat comment in your code when you do it.

Comment: First, there are always comments. :)
But it is always up to the developer not to screw up his work. Why limit the tools you have just because it is not "obvious"? Also, in this case, like in most method swizzling cases, the swizzling is transparent. Calling `[b foo]`, swizzled or not, will have the same expected behavior and return the same type.